# how to put two variables from a dataset on a bar graph stacked in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to put two variables of a datatable in a bar chart (available and unavailable) in percentage (y axis) and Date in x axis for each service (color in the plotly to differentiate the services). This is my datatable with respective variables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkIU6.png)

And I am trying to combine these two variables in a single graph taking into account each service (Serie). At this moment I only got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II12f.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the reproducible sample. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to generate the reproducible sample.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this using plotly in R

```
barstack<-plot_ly(Servicelevel, x=Servicelevel$Date, y=Servicelevel$Available,
                             color=Servicelevel$Series,type = "bar")
    barstack <- barstack %>% add_trace(y = Servicelevel$Unavailable)
    barstack<-barstack %>% 
      layout(title = "Percentage of Availability over time",
             yaxis = list(title = 'Availability (%)',
                          tickformat = ".2%"),
             xaxis=list(title='Date'), barmode = 'stack')
```

And result is this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWym9.png)